# How to get Entities synchronously while using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to get storage account's Table's data.
I succeed in getting the date using the way [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs#query-a-set-of-entities).

But it's using callback. I want to get the results synchronously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function which returns `Promise` to make it `synchronous` (or simulate it)

```
function getSome(mytable, hometasks, num)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tableSvc.retrieveEntity(mytable, hometasks, num, function(error, result, response){
      if(!error){
        resolve(entity // result or response etc)
      } else {
        reject(error)
      }
    });
  })
```

Then you can use elsewhere in your code with `async/await` (to pause execution) like

Note you can use `await` only inside `async` function

```
async function useData() {
  const data = await getSome('mytable', 'hometasks', '1');
  // use data here
}
```

or with plain promise as (Note, this does not pause execution, code inside `then` is a callback function again)

```
const data = getSome('mytable', 'hometasks', '1');
data.then(res => // do something)
```

Also looks like `cosmos` have now [`sdk`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js) with `Promise` support.

Read more about [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) on MDN